# Debug with Attach to dotnet core process on Mac always lead to the error: Unknown Error: 0x80070459

Tags: .net-core

I used to be able to attach to the dotnet core (**dotnet 2.2**) process on my **Mac Mojave**. But it seems that after the installation of dotnet 3.0, it always fail to attach to the dotnet process with the following error: `Unknown Error: 0x80070459`.

I have been googling this issue for a month but haven't found a solution to this problem.

It seems to be relevant to my system issue. It would be really appreciated if anyone has a solution to this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Similar issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/1406), somebody needs to write a better bug report to make progress on this.

Comment: @Hans Passant Yea I saw this post as well,but I have tried almost every possible solutions, none of them work, like restarting, reinstalling of 2.2.207,etc. Nothing works, it really prevents me from productivity